# SAS Encoding is getting changed automatically

Tags: encoding, utf-8, sas

I am using SAS 9.3 Server Edition.

Default Encoding is set to UTF-8 in the ".cfg" file. And when I start SAS directly it has UTF-8 as its default encoding.

However, when I open sas via opening a sas program, the encoding gets changed to "WLATIN-1".

Any idea why this could be happening and how shall it be fixed.

Comment: When you say server edition, do you mean you're using enterprise guide, or you are logged into the server and using display manager?

Answer (score 0):

What's probably happening is that you are loading a different config file when SAS is being started via explorer as opposed to you starting SAS directly.  How to fix that depends on some complexity, unfortunately.

The simplest fix is to ensure that all of your config files are UTF-8.  If you installed SAS as a Unicode Server, this should be the case; however, if you installed over a previous version, or if you installed multiple languages, this might not be the case.  Usually, the default config file in %SASHOME%\SASFoundation\9.x\sasv9.cfg is a pointer to another config file (likely \nls\en\ ) - change that, if it does point there, to \nls\u8.  That config file is used when a config file is not specified in the executable line (which it may not be).

You can also use regedit to fiddle with the options for what happens when a .sas file is opened.  [SAS kb 821](http://support.sas.com/kb/45/821.html) gives some guidance for how to do that; the main idea is to find the CLS ID for SAS, expand HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\, or if 32 bit on 64 bit machine, HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\, and look at the LocalServer and possibly LocalServer32 nodes - they should contain the startup command.  Add (or more likely, correct) your -cfg option from your shortcut to those.